How do I make Typescript understand that one argument can be used as a discriminant property for another object argument?
In the below code, Typescript does not narrow the type of obj based on its property type.
Why is it not working and how do I fix it?
type Types = "Foo" | "Bar";

interface ObjOne {
  one: "one";
  two: "two";
}

interface ObjTwo {
  three: "three";
  four: "four";
}

type ExtractRelatedObject<T extends Types> = T extends "Foo"
  ? ObjOne
  : T extends "Bar"
    ? ObjTwo
    : never;

interface Baz<T extends Types> {
  type: T;
  relatedObject: ExtractRelatedObject<T>;
}

function foo<T extends Types>(obj: Baz<T>) {
  if (obj.type === "Bar") {
    obj.relatedObject.three;
    //^?? Property 'three' does not exist on type 'ObjOne | ObjTwo'.
  }
}


I tried a few things and found out the following:
This works:
function fooFix1(obj: Baz<"Foo"> | Baz<"Bar">) {
  if (obj.type === "Bar") {
    obj.relatedObject.three;
                     // ^?? ObjTwo.three: "three"
  }
}

This does not work:
(I added a default type to the type parameter, hoping it would spread the generic into a union type so that the distributive conditional type would work)
function fooBroken1<T extends Types = Types>(obj: Baz<T>) {
  if (obj.type === "Bar") {
    obj.relatedObject.three;
    //^?? Property 'three' does not exist on type 'ObjOne | ObjTwo'.
  }
}

Playground link.

I have narrowed the issue down to the generic in foo. If we swap out obj: Baz<T> with a union of possible object types, then it starts working as intended. It would be great with an answer explaining why that is, and if there is a smart way to create the union instead of explicitly spelling it out: Baz<'Foo'> | Baz<'Bar'>

Why use a complicate ExtractRelatedObject helper? Rather just use a discriminated union to declare the Baz type in the first place

Thanks @Bergi ,that is probably a good idea. The OP is a simplified MVP. The actual code is a more complex React application, where Baz represents the props for a component. Regardless, I should be able to just define Baz directly as a discriminated union, as you say.

@Bergi In the use-case I am facing, I get two properties into component A, one of which is a list of Baz. Component A then returns a new React component B, which is passed each Baz element from the list. If I do not make this generic, will it not try to assign all possible union members of component B props, into function component B's props? I.e. not one-to-one? The code does not work at the moment, with an error that seems like it is trying to assign Baz<'Foo'> to Baz<'Bar'>, etc.

I don't quite follow. You might want to ask a separate question with code regarding your actual use case

@Bergi Good call, I made a follow-up question here, all input is deeply appreciated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78740937/how-to-get-two-components-in-typescript-to-understand-that-their-properties-matc

TypeScript raises an error because T extends "Foo" | "Bar" doesn't just admit the specific types "Foo" and "Bar", but also the union type "Foo" | "Bar", and Baz<"Foo" | "Bar"> resolves to
{ 
  type: "Foo" | "Bar",
  relatedObject: ExtractRelatedObject<"Foo" | "Bar">,
}

which allows a caller to make different choices in type and relatedObject:
const x: Baz<Types> = {
  type: "Bar",      
  relatedObject: {  
    one: "one",
    two: "two",
  }
}
foo(x);

That is, your method signature permits type and relatedObject to disagree, which is why your method implementation may not assume that they match.
To prevent this, your method signature should use a type that only admits Baz<"Foo"> or Baz<"Bar">, but not Baz<"Foo" | "Bar">. One way to get such a type is to index into a mapped type instead:
type Baz = {[T in Types]: {
  type: T,
  relatedObject: ExtractRelatedObject<T>;
}};

function foo(obj: Baz[Types]) {
  ...
}

because indexing a mapped type distributes the union, turning Baz["Foo" | "Bar"] into Baz["Foo"] | Baz["Bar"], which is the type we want.
PS: Indexing could also simplify your definition of ExtractRelatedObject:
type RelatedObject = {
  "Foo": ObjOne,
  "Bar": ObjTwo,
}

type Baz = {[T in Types]: {
  type: T,
  relatedObject: RelatedObject[T];
}};


Thank you. I tried indexing Baz with T, but it did not work. Any idea why? Example (line 35): https://tsplay.dev/mxOjXN

I also tried your solution in the below follow-up question, but unfortunately could not get it to work. If you have time, any input on why over on that post would be appreciated. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78740937/how-to-get-two-components-in-typescript-to-understand-that-their-properties-matc

You can write a type predicate for obj is Baz<"Bar">, and use that instead of obj.type === "Bar".
function isBar(obj: Baz<any>): obj is Baz<"Bar">
{
  return obj.type === "Bar";
}

function foo<T extends Types>(obj: Baz<T>) {
  if (isBar(obj)) {
    obj.relatedObject.three;
  } 
}

N.b. this doesn't infer ObjOne in an else case, so you will probably need an isFoo predicate too.
Playground
The reason your original formulation doesn't work is that Types is still a valid substitution for T. When you switch to the union Baz<"Foo"> | Baz<"Bar">, it isn't, so the condition does allow T to be narrowed to "Bar". You could think of the original case as the union Baz<"Foo"> | Baz<"Bar"> | Baz<"Foo" | "Bar">.
An alternative method is to add some type inference
interface IBaz<T extends Types> {
  type: T;
  relatedObject: ExtractRelatedObject<T>;
}

type Baz<T> = T extends infer A extends Types ? IBaz<A> : never;

Playground

Thanks Caleth. Please see my comment to the OP, I think the culprit is the generic.

@Magnus see edit. In finding out how to easily define Baz<"Foo"> | Baz<"Bar"> I found something that fits your original definition of foo

Interesting, makes sense re. the Baz<"Foo" | "Bar">. If you have time, could you add an explanation of why / how the infer works?

@Magnus I don't know the exact mechanism, but I found this so answer
