How to get two components in TypeScript to understand that their properties match in type?
This is a follow-up question to: How do I make Typescript understand that one argument can be used as a discriminant property for another object argument?
The problem is best explained with code:
type Types = "Foo" | "Bar";

interface ObjOne {
  one: "one";
  two: "two";
}

interface ObjTwo {
  three: "three";
  four: "four";
}

type ExtractRelatedObject<T extends Types> = T extends "Foo"
  ? ObjOne
  : T extends "Bar"
    ? ObjTwo
    : never;

interface Baz<T extends Types> {
  type: T;
  relatedObject: ExtractRelatedObject<T>;
  arrayOfRelatedObject: Array<ExtractRelatedObject<T>>
}

function componentOne({type, relatedObject, arrayOfRelatedObject}: Baz<"Foo"> | Baz<"Bar">) {
  if (type === "Bar") {
    relatedObject.three;
    arrayOfRelatedObject.map(relObj => relObj)
  }
}

interface ComponentTwoProps<T extends Types> {
  type: T
  arrayOfRelatedObject: Array<ExtractRelatedObject<T>>
}

function componentTwo<T extends Types>({type, arrayOfRelatedObject}: ComponentTwoProps<T>) {
  arrayOfRelatedObject.map((relObj, index, arr) => {
   return componentOne({type, relatedObject: relObj, arrayOfRelatedObject: arr }) 
  })
}

Playground link.
TypeScript does not understand that arr and relObj are related, and somehow tries to cross-assign arr.
What is wrong here, and how can it be fixed?

I attempted the solution provided by @meriton in the linked SO question above, but without success: Playground link.

This is some yucky ms/TS#30581 stuff and the solution will probably involve ms/TS#47109 but I'm traveling now and can't look at it much. Maybe someone can refactor to generics in the right way before I get to it, otherwise I'll look when I can.

Currently this version is the closest I can get. The problem is that TS either wants to do control flow analysis (like switch/case stuff) or generics, and not both. If someone finds something better than this that works without loosening type safety, I'd be interested to see it. I'll look more when I can also.
